How to list all machines attached to a pro subscription?
I have just activated a private pro subscription and attached one machine. But my 'Pro Dashboard' lists two attached machines. How can I get a list of the attached machines from the dashboard?

does this help? https://documentation.ubuntu.com/pro/active-machines/

you can also see the manpage here https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/en/man1/ubuntu-advantage.1.html

@graham answer it or I will ;-)

@Rinzwind a true gentleman - now done

I'm facing the same problem. I attached 2 machines and the dashboard (beta) tells me it detected 4 machines. I have been very conservative of using the service in the past, partially due to lack of documentation. On the Red Hat side it works as intended. I understand that with the rebranding and adding of features or stronger promotion (ESM) this is intended to increase cash flow for Canonical from home labbers and professionals looking for such solutions. (I support that.) Therefore, a broken feature on a dashboard should not be answered with "you find answers in the manual". No you can not.

You can obtain an active machine count through the Ubuntu Pro Dashboard for each subscription to Ubuntu Pro. This gives the number of online machines attached to your Pro token that have pinged Canonical Servers within the last 24 hours. If a machine is detached from your token the reduction in active machine count will not be seen for 24 hours until 24 hours later.
See https://documentation.ubuntu.com/pro/active-machines/
The man page which explains further how to manage the Ubuntu Pro services from Canonical can be viewed here and is your official reference.
For example, it provides a list of commands which can be used in relation to the management of your subscription including status which indicates whether the service is enabled on the machine where the command is performed, as well as status --simulate-with-token which will shows whether the service is set to be  enabled when that  token is attached.

So, there is no way to get a list of all attached machines either from command line or from https://ubuntu.com/pro/dashboard This is rather odd! :(

@FedKad I guess not given the fluidity of the attached machines. Thanks for the edit BTW.

Seems anyone who can grab my key, for example from my ~/.bash_history, can attach their machine with it and I'd have no way of knowing who that is.

As you attach machines, you will see your active machine count go above your license count. This is expected behavior and will not impact your access to the Pro services.
There will always be a discrepancy between active machine count and license count. I got this off of UBUNTU site

There are many Ubuntu sites, and a few dodgy unofficial sites. Which one was this information on?
